# implement janus gateway for webrtc

Tags: webrtc, janus-gateway

I am following janus documentation to build a video mcu system. I installed all the dependencies of it according to the read me file.  
`http://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/`

after that when I run the script using `sh install.sh`   I am getting following error

```
In file included from test.c:1:0:
../websock/src/websock.h:55:26: fatal error: event2/event.h: No such file or directory
 #include <event2/event.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [test.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gayan/MyDetails/MyApplications/virtualClassRoomTest/janus-gateway/wstest'
make: *** [wstest] Error 2

The installer couldn't find the libwebsock lib, which is needed for WebSockets
You can install version 1.0.4 (required!) with the following steps:
    wget http://paydensutherland.com/libwebsock-1.0.4.tar.gz
    tar xfv libwebsock-1.0.4.tar.gz
    cd libwebsock-1.0.4
    ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install

    [Note: you may need to pass --libdir=/usr/lib64 to the configure script if you're installing on a x86_64 distribution]

If you're not interested in WebSockets support, you can disable them passing nowebsockets to the install script:
    ./install.sh nowebsockets
```

I also install the libwebsock according to the above steps, but still the error is showing. event2 directory is not in the janus-gateway codes. here is the github link for all the source code. https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway.git
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing libwebsocket is not in your path...Also, did you clean and make again?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Benjamin. libwebsocket is inside the janus-gateway folder as the document instructs. I also did _make clean_ and _make_ again. But the result is same. as I mentioned earlier, event2 folder and event.h file is also not in the source codes.

Comment: And you don't have a 64 bit OS? I have done exactly what you have done and it worked fine on Debian Jessie x86. Also, LibWebsocket is NOT to be in the janus-gateway folder...It is to be INSTALLED and located in your PATH. Most likely the lib file in `/usr/lib/` and the include files in `/usr/include/`.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent   Can you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262133/janus-gateway-configure-shows-websockets-not-enabled)   Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

The full installation steps to have websockets working(Ubuntu 14) are:

```
mkdir -p ~/build

sudo apt-get install libmicrohttpd-dev libjansson-dev libnice-dev libssl-dev libsrtp-dev libsofia-sip-ua-dev libglib2.0-dev libopus-dev libogg-dev libini-config-dev libcollection-dev libwebsockets-dev pkg-config gengetopt automake libtool doxygen graphviz git cmake

sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev

echo "Start installing libwebsockets"
cd ~/build
git clone git://git.libwebsockets.org/libwebsockets
cd libwebsockets
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr  -DLWS_SERVER_OPTION_DO_SSL_GLOBAL_INIT=ON ..
make && sudo make install

echo "Start installing Janus"
cd ~/build
git clone git://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway.git
cd janus-gateway
sh autogen.sh
./configure --disable-data-channels --disable-rabbitmq --disable-docs --prefix=/opt/janus LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"

make && sudo make install
sudo make configs
```

Make sure to copy certificates if using wss, chrome is really picky about that stuff. If using self signed certificates you have to trust them in chrome(very intuitive procedure:)))

```
sudo cp mycert.pem /opt/janus/share/janus/certs/
sudo cp mycert.key /opt/janus/share/janus/certs/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solve it after

> sudo apt-get install libevent-dev

My system is ubuntu 14.04 64 bit