# janus gateway: configure shows websockets not enabled

Tags: websocket, libwebsockets, janus-gateway

I am trying to use janus. First step, installation.
I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway). All is well. However, when I run

```
    configure prefix=/opt/janus
```

Relevant portions of the output are:

```
...
checking for TRANSPORTS... yes
checking for MHD... yes
checking for lws_create_vhost in -lwebsockets... no
checking for amqp_error_string2 in -lrabbitmq... no
checking for MQTTAsync_create in -lpaho-mqtt3a... no
checking for PLUGINS... yes
checking for SOFIA... yes
checking for OPUS... yes
checking for OGG... yes
checking for EVENTS... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating html/Makefile
config.status: creating docs/Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

libsrtp version:           1.5.x
SSL/crypto library:        OpenSSL
DTLS set-timeout:          not available
DataChannels support:      no
Recordings post-processor: no
TURN REST API client:      yes
Doxygen documentation:     no
Transports:
    REST (HTTP/HTTPS):     yes
    WebSockets:            no
    RabbitMQ:              no
    MQTT:                  no
    Unix Sockets:          yes
Plugins:
    Echo Test:             yes
    Streaming:             yes
    Video Call:            yes
    SIP Gateway:           yes
    Audio Bridge:          yes
    Video Room:            yes
    Voice Mail:            yes
    Record&Play:           yes
    Text Room:             yes
```

MY PROBLEM IS WITH THE ENTRY **WebSockets:  no.**

I checked in /usr/lib and here are the relevant files there:

```
 /usr/lib/libwebsockets.a  /usr/lib/libwebsockets.so  
 /usr/lib/libwebsockets.so.11  /usr/lib/libwebsockets.so.5
```

And in /usr/include

```
 /usr/include/libwebsockets.h
```

So, I think that libwebsockets is installed properly.  What needs to be done to get the webSockets transport enabled?

I did look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866712/implement-janus-gateway-for-webrtc) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/pull/996

You need libwebsockets >= 2.0.0. Trusty has an old version.

You have to compile it. See the description of janus how to do that.

Comment: You would better remove libwebsockets-dev before compiling

Comment: Yes. That was it!